# How to enlarge size of wsl2?

Tags: wsl2, diskpart

The WSL2 says it uses more than 90% size.

```
  System information as of Sat Jul 30 22:52:35 CST 2022

  System load:                      0.107421875
  Usage of /:                       90.7% of 250.98GB
  Memory usage:                     10%
  Swap usage:                       0%
  Processes:                        44
  Users logged in:                  0
  IPv4 address for br-345a7fa3f56b: 172.18.0.1
  IPv4 address for docker0:         172.17.0.1
  IPv4 address for eth0:            172.31.228.161

  => / is using 90.7% of 250.98GB
```

However, DISKPART says `Virtual size:  500 GB`

```
DISKPART> detail vdisk

Device type ID: 0 (Unknown)
Vendor ID: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} (Unknown)
State: Added
Virtual size:  500 GB
Physical size:  235 GB
Filename: E:\WSL2\ubuntu\ext4.vhdx
Is Child: No
Parent Filename:
Associated disk#: Not found.
```

This is output of `Get-VHD –Path xxx`

```
ComputerName            : DESKTOP-RMF966H
Path                    : E:\WSL2\ubuntu\ext4.vhdx
VhdFormat               : VHDX
VhdType                 : Dynamic
FileSize                : 253127294976
Size                    : 536870912000
MinimumSize             :
LogicalSectorSize       : 512
PhysicalSectorSize      : 4096
BlockSize               : 1048576
ParentPath              :
DiskIdentifier          : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
FragmentationPercentage : 100
Alignment               : 1
Attached                : True
DiskNumber              :
IsPMEMCompatible        : False
AddressAbstractionType  : None
Number                  :
```

Why can't the wsl2 recognize the 500GB?

Comment: Have you tried actually looking at the VHD info using `Get-VHD` ?  I know this isn't an answer.. but if it were me, I would start by skipping the virtualized OS and simply look at the file.  Try [this](https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/gathering-vhd-info-get-vhd-powershell/) and take it from there.. you might have your own answer.  If not, you will have more information to update your question with.

Comment: Thank you.  I have updated the question with this info.

Comment: Do you have enough free space on the host drive?

Comment: Yes, the host drive is 2TB.

Comment: You'll still need to resize the filesystem inside wsl, I suppose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/vhd-size) on resizing the VHD.  Specifically, as mentioned in the comments, you'll need to resize the ext4 filesystem after expanding the virtual drive itself.

I'm going to add to the Microsoft doc instructions slightly here to make it a bit more robust:

- First, exit any WSL session and `wsl --shutdown`.  This will make sure that only one WSL2 instance is running in case you do happen to have multiple distributions.  And while you may not, a future reader may, so better to be safe.
- Then start the WSL2 instance that you need to resize and:

  ```
  sudo mount -t devtmpfs none /dev
  ```

  This will most likely result in an error that it is already mounted, which you can safely ignore.

  ```
  mount | grep ext4
  ```
- Use the output to identify the drive for this WSL2 instance, which will be something like `/dev/sd<X>` (e.g. `/dev/sdb`).
- Resize the filesystem via:

  ```
  sudo resize2fs /dev/sd<X> <sizeInMegabytes>M
  ```

  For instance:

  ```
  sudo resize2fs /dev/sdb 500M
  ```

Comment: Thank you. I followed the instruction but... the info doesn't change either. However, I think I found the problem that the info shown isn't refreshed in time. 
I like your answer which is working.